# Getting 404 on all outbound HTTP calls from pods inside istio mesh

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have istio v1.1.6 installed on Kubernetes v1.11 using [Helm chart](https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/aa554e7/install/kubernetes/helm) provided in istio repository with bunch of overrides including:

```
global:
  outboundTrafficPolicy:
    mode: ALLOW_ANY
pilot:
  env:
    PILOT_ENABLE_FALLTHROUGH_ROUTE: "1"
mixer:
  enabled: true
galley:
  enabled: true
security:
  enabled: false
```

The problem is that I can't make any simple outbound HTTP request to a service running on port 80 (inside & outside of the mesh) from a pod which is inside istio mesh and has istio-proxy injected as sidecar. The response is always 404:

```sh
user@pod-12345-12345$ curl -v http://httpbin.org/headers
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 52.200.83.146...
* Connected to httpbin.org (52.200.83.146) port 80 (#0)
> GET /headers HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: httpbin.org
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< date: Wed, 15 May 2019 05:43:24 GMT
* Server envoy is not blacklisted
< server: envoy
< content-length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host httpbin.org left intact
```

The [response flag](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/access_log#config-access-log-format-response-flags) in the istio-proxy logs from envoy states that it can't find the proper route:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 NR "-" 0 0 0 - "-" "curl/7.38.0" "238d0799-f83d-4e5e-94e7-79de4d14fa53" "httpbin.org" "-" - - 172.217.27.14:80 100.99.149.201:52892 -
```

> NR: No route configured for a given request in addition to 404 response code.

Probably worths to add that:

- Other outbound calls to any ports other than 80 works perfectly fine.
- Checking `proxy-status` also shows nothing: all pods are SYNCED.
- mTLS is disabled
- The example above is a call to external service but calls to internal services (eg: `curl another-service.svc.cluster.local/health`) have the same issue.
- I expecte calls to internal mesh services work out of the box, tho even I tried to define `DestinationRoute` and `ServiceEntry` and that did not help as well.
- I don't really want to add  `traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundIPRanges: "0.0.0.0/0"` annotation to deployment as according to docs:

  > this approach completely bypasses the sidecar, essentially disabling all of Istio’s features for the specified IPs

Any idea where else I can look or what is missing?

Comment: You might want to add a config dump from the Istio-proxy: Create a port-forward to port 15000 of your Pod, and then run `curl localhost:15000/config_dump`.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you have a short connection timeouts defined in your istio-proxy sidecar, please check [here](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/1555) similar github issue of Envoy's project.

btw. as @Robert Panzer mentioned, sharing the whole dump of istio-proxy config would help much in investigating your particular case.